# digital signature on a calculator or a spreadsheet cell

Tags: excel, cryptography, spreadsheet, digital-signature

Is it possible to calculate something like DSA signature using a simple calculator like a spreadsheet processor?

I need to calculate numeric signatures for table column data (numeric too) and check that signature later to make sure the document has no new entries not signed by me (I need to check only the column in question and only the entries I calculated signatures for).

Is that, to any extent, achievable by just doing some common-precision math in a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

Possible? Almost certainly. Doable? Hardly. Advisable? Probably not.

First of all, you'd first need a symmetric hash implementation. Then you need math on exceedingly high values. Both can be constructed from the common precision math available to you. However, it would be rather difficult to implement, and - once implemented - exceedingly slow. It could also be pretty tricky to keep the private key secure.

If you want to do this is would be very wise to break out to a general programming language. For Excel that's probably VBA. In that case you could probably use a generic API to perform your signature generation (RSA-PSS would probably be best). You may want to calculate the hash locally and generate the signature in a secured environment.

Comment: the environment is a very limited database engine that can do simple math and the use of external APIs is impossible in my scenario. Actually I want to sign user IDs.